# Multiple select option update once button pressed

Tags: javascript

In the following example code, when the 'Add Chapter' button is pressed, a chapter should be added (a prompt asks the user for the chapter title). There are two places where the new chapter element needs to be inserted into the DOM.

However, when the 'Add Chapter' button is pressed an error is shown after the value is entered into the prompt box.

Could anyone provide me with some help?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div id="mainsec1" style="border: 1pt solid; width: 40%;padding: 10pt">
        <div id="sec1">
          <span class="head1">Chapter</span>
            
          <select name="startype" id="starselect">
            <option selected="selected" />
            <option value="Aquila">Aquila</option>
            <option value="Centaurus">Centaurus</option>
            <option value="Canis Major">Canis Major</option>
          </select>
          <span class="head1">
            <input type="button" class="buttonit" value="Delete" onclick="Delerow();" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <div id="sec2">
          <span class="head1">Heading</span>

          <select name="startypeHead" id="starheading">
            <option selected="selected" />
            <option value="Aquila">Aquila Heading</option>
            <option value="Centaurus">Centaurus Heading</option>
            <option value="Canis Major">Canis Major Heading</option>
          </select>
          <span class="head1">
            <input type="button" class="buttonit" value="Delete" onclick="Delerowsub();" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <input type="button" class="buttonit" value="Add Heading" onclick="AddHead();" />
      </div>
      <div id="mainsec2" style="margin-top: 10pt;border: 1pt solid; width: 40%;padding: 10pt">
        <div id="sec3">
          <span class="head1">Chapter</span>

          <select name="startypechap" id="starselectchap">
            <option selected="selected" />
            <option value="Aquila">Aquila Chapter</option>
            <option value="Centaurus">Centaurus Chapter</option>
            <option value="Canis Major">Canis Major  Chapter</option>
          </select>
          <span class="head1">
            <input type="button" class="buttonit" value="Delete" onclick="Delerow();" />
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="button" class="buttonitonsub" value="Add Chapter" onclick="AddChap();" />
    </form>
  <script>
    var glovar;
    document.getElementById('starselect').onchange = function(){
      var list = document.forms[0].startype;
      glovar = list.selectedIndex;
      var sublist = document.forms[0].startypeHead;
      sublist.selectedIndex = glovar;
    }
    function AddHead(){
      var inpVal = prompt("Input your Heading", "Heading");
      var select = document.getElementById("starheading"); 
      var opele = document.createElement("option");
      opele.value = inpVal;
      opele.text = inpVal;
      select.add(opele);
    }
    function AddChap(){
      var inpVal=prompt("Input your Chapter", "Chapter");
      var select = document.getElementById("starselectchap"); 
      var select1 = document.getElementById("starselect"); //Here, I am trying to get the required element.
      var opele = document.createElement("option");
      opele.value = inpVal;
      opele.text = inpVal;
      select.add(opele);
      alert(select1.add(opele));
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/posiyawu/2/edit?html,js,output) to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding the newly created DOM element to the first select, it cannot be added to the second select. You will need to create two elements to add to the DOM:

```
var inpVal=prompt("Input your Chapter", "Chapter");
var select = document.getElementById("starselectchap"); 
var select1 = document.getElementById("starselect"); // Here, I am trying to get the required element.
var opele = document.createElement("option");
opele.value = inpVal;
opele.text = inpVal;
var opele1 = document.createElement("option");
opele1.value = inpVal;
opele1.text = inpVal;
// Or use opele.cloneNode(), depending on your browser support.
select.add(opele);
select1.add(opele1);
```

That will fix the issue. I would really recommend running you JavaScript code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).